# Binomial in Statistics

Tags: statistics

I was asked a question;
A student was late for college 0.25 of the time, what is the probability he is late 4 days in one college week. My answer was this:

L = Late, N = Not Late

L = 0.25, N = 0.75

if its a 7 day week

P(L+N)7 = L7 + (7C1)L6 N + (7C2)L5N2+(7C3)L4N3+(7C4)L3N4+…

P(4L, 3N) = (7C3)(0.25)4(0.75)3 = 0.057

If it’s a 5 day week

P(L+N)5 = L5+ (5C1)L4 N + (5C2)L3N2+(5C3)L2N3+(5C4)LN4+…

P(4L1N) = (5C1)(0.25)4(0.75) = 0.0146

Have I got this ok?

Comment: Essentially yes, though you should use MathJax so we can read what you are saying.

Comment: $$0.25 \% = 0.0025 \ne 25\%,$$ that is to say, a quarter of a percent is not the same thing as twenty-five percent.

Comment: Computations in R where `dbinom` is binomial PDF: $X$ = days late per wk. Five day week. P(X = 4).  `dbinom(4, 5, .25)` returns 0.01464844. Seven day week:
`dbinom(4, 7, .25)` returns 0.05767822. // If it's _at least 4,_ then you have a different problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, note that the binomial function is as follows:

$P(X=x) = \binom{n}{x}p^{x}(1-p)^{n-x}$

For example, if $Pr$(late)$=0.25$ and he is late $n=4$ times that week (assuming a week is 7 days), then

$P(X=4) = \binom{7}{4}(.25)^4(1-.25)^{3} \approx 0.057678$

Therefore, there is a 5.77% chance that the student is late 4 out of the 7 days that week.

Does this help?

Comment: OK (+1), but fixed position of decimal point.

Comment: @Mrlemons109 I hope I answered your question well!

Answer (score 0):

Comment to show relevant graphs (made using R):

7 day week.

```
x = 0:7; pdf.7 = dbinom(x, 7, .25)
plot(x, pdf.7, ylab="PDF", type="h", lwd=2, col="blue",
     main="PDF of BINOM(7, .25)")
 lines(5,pdf.7[6], type="h", lwd=3, col="maroon")
 abline(h=0, col="green2")
```

$P(X = 4)$ shown in maroon.

[image]

5 day week.

```
x = 0:5; pdf.5 = dbinom(x, 5, .25)
plot(x, pdf.5, ylab="PDF", type="h", lwd=2, col="blue",
     main="PDF of BINOM(5, .25)")
 lines(5,pdf.5[6], type="h", lwd=3, col="maroon")
 abline(h=0, col="green2")
```

$P(X = 4)$ shown in maroon, but is (almost) too small to see.

[image]